# OAuth v2 Authorization Code returned in Location HTTP header

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-365

I am using the OAuth to obtain an access token from Microsoft Graph. I am specifically using the Authorization Code grant type. The first step is to request a Code via an HTTP GET. The code is then used in a second HTTP POST API call along with the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

What is confusing me is how the Authorization Code is being delivered. It is returned as part of the HTTP Headers named Location.

[image: HTTP Response Header]

Is this expected? I was looking for it in a response body similar to how an `access_token` is returned. Is returning the Code via the `Location` header expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AUTHORIZATION CODE FLOW**

This flow is very standard for browser clients, so behaviour looks correct:

- The browser receives the authorization code as part of a redirect, where there are security risks, such as the code being included in logs or visible to the user, or possibly being intercepted by a malicious party.
- The UI's logic then makes a direct HTTPS call to swap the code for tokens. Using two stages to get OAuth tokens reduces the threat surface for browser clients.

**TESTING THE CODE FLOW**

The Code Flow is tricky to test in tools like Postman. Have a look at [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools) as a better alternative - see also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr0SECFMoU4).

Here are some values of mine you can use as a first step:

- Select Add Environment and enter the base Azure AD URL, which for my developer account has this value as issuer, then click discover to populate other endpoints:
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/v2.0
- Then start a Code Flow with a client id such as this one of mine: c5ea6d78-c637-4f7f-b238-2264f5d4b479
- Then, once the settings look like the below screenshot, start a login redirect:

[image: Code Flow Settings]

You can then update to your own settings and do the same thing with a test user. Then scroll down and select the 'Redeem Code' option, and use the client_secret_post option to swap the code for tokens. Then view the JWT details etc.

One problem is that my Azure AD client is a Single Page App and Azure AD requires this header to be added to the curl request during the redeem step. Not sure if you will face that problem and I will see if I can get the tool updated to allow extra headers etc to be typed in.

- -H 'Origin: https://web.mycompany.com'

Comment: Thanks for the help. My intent is to use a browser to request the Auth code and then once obtaining the Auth code then make a second POST using the Auth code to request a token. I am just doing this in the Postman client to confirm that I have the process working correctly before coding it. Does that help?

Comment: Yep - all looks correct then Mr webworm - I've edited my answer - have a look at the test option above also